# Jquery ajax request fails on chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

i have to make an ajax request to a PHP file to update the database. The PHP file should be called when i click on a link. Here's the jquery code i use:

```
$("a#email_contatti").click(function(){
   $.get("/segna_mail.php",{sito:'mywebsite'});
});
```

It works fine on Firefox 4/5 and Safari..But Chrome ( v14.0.797.0 but it does not work also on other versions) seems to cut the request and it does not update the db.. I tried also to access the PHP script via url and there it works fine also on Chrome.. 
Someone told me to add the return false at the end of the function. Tried also this but it breaks the link ( it's a mailto link ). I have no more ideas..

Thanks, Andrea

Comment: I had this same issue. I had to use a POST instead of a get to fix it. Seems like a bug in chrome

Comment: Is this running locally on your machine?

Comment: Chrome has very strict cross-domain restrictions. Do you call segna_mail.php on the same domain, your javascript runs on?

Comment: @Joe Tried also using $.post..nothing
@Decad It is running on a web server
@pex Yup, it is from the same domain
Thanks all of you :)

Answer (score 0):

`GET` is meant to perform an operation that retrieves data, `POST` is meant to send data to a server (and most probably do something with it, like a database `INSERT`). So I imagine that Chrome may be cutting off / not sending the JSON data you're providing.

From what I take of what you're trying to do, it's better for you to use `POST` anyway. Try it out if that works.

If you really want to try it out with `GET`, try `$.get('/segna_mail.php?sito=mywebsite')` instead.

Comment: I've already tried with post. The "segna_mail.php" script has to update a database record. Here's the code i used..(Same of before but with post :-) )
`$("a#email_contatti").click(function(){$.post("/segna_mail.php",{sito:'produzione.sviluppa.it'});});`

Comment: Well, your syntax is definitely correct. From experience though, you may want to pass in a data string similar to a query string (or that chucked out by the `.serialize()` function). That got it working on my end for Chrome. Barring that, maybe you can try it out with the low-level `$.ajax()` function instead, and see if there's any difference?

Comment: Uhm..I could try with $.ajax, but i've read that it gaves the same problem..I'm stuck here! :-(